# Default initializion value of boolean member in struct

Tags: c, struct

If I have the following

```
struct a {
        int a;
        int b;
        bool c;
}
```

and use the following initialization function

```
struct ls *ls_new(struct ls **ls, size_t *size)
{
        struct ls *m, *n;
        n = realloc(*ls, (*size + 1) * sizeof(struct ls));
        if (!n)
                return NULL;

        *ls = n;
        m = *ls + *size;
        (*size)++;

        // init struct
        *m = (struct ls) {.a = 0}

        return m;
}
```

When I use `ls_new()` to initialize an instance of `struct a` the `c99` standard guarantees that initializing one member of the struct will also initialize all other members. What will be the default initialization value for `bool c`?

Comment: Why don't you test it and find out?

Comment: `return m` --> `return m;`

Comment: @SouravGhosh, typo. Thanks.

Comment: @stanpines Because 'testing' is not an ideal approach to clarify properties of a language, especially concerning C and C++, where the concept of _undefined behaviour_ permits different compilers to handle things differently.

Comment: The expressions `*size + 1` and `*ls + *size` and `(*size)++` should give you errors.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `ls` is passed in as a double pointer.

Comment: Read [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

Comment: I'm talking about the `size` argument, which is not passed as a pointer. If posting actual code, the *copy and paste* the actual code, instead of rewriting it in the post, then you won't get errors in the posted code that willl distract from your actual problem. Either that, or create a brand new [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us, also copied-and-pasted.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, just figured. Typo, thanks! Function's taken from a pretty big codebase. I edited a lot of stuff.

Comment: I assume you mean `*m = (struct ls) {.a = 0};`.

Comment: @Lundin, yes, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What will be the default initialization value for bool c?

It is `0`, i.e., `false`.

From:

> (C99, 6.7.8p22) "If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration."

and

> (C99, 6.7.8p10) "If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly,
>   then: [...]
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;

And `_Bool` (which `bool` macros expands to) is an arithmetic type.

Comment: Might be good to note that all integral types will default to `0`. +1 regardless.